# During the data fetching by API, some of the fields are missing how i can manage it?

Tags: python, dataframe, api, debugging

''''''    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\KHUSHB~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8780/1143884894.py in 
9     longitude.append(i['location']['longitude'])
10     precision.append(i['location']['precision'])
---> 11     postalCode.append(i['location']['postalCode'])
12
13 d={"address":address,"latitude":latitude,"longitude":longitude,"precision":precision,"postalCode":postalCode}

```
KeyError: 'postalCode'
```

'''''

[snapshop of Jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPHkr.png)

Comment: you could use a try catch block or check if that that key is in that path before you append. would you mind posting your code instead of a screenshot of it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.